# mysql return two minimum values

Tags: mysql

I have a table named: workers and a table named: schedule with the following format:

workers:

```
| id | name      | vacationA  | vacationB  | workhistory |
|  1 | Florin    | 2017-05-05 | 2017-05-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  2 | Andrei    | 2017-06-05 | 2017-06-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  3 | Alexandra | 2017-07-05 | 2017-07-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  4 | Emilia    | 2017-08-05 | 2017-08-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  5 | Nicoleta  | 2017-09-05 | 2017-09-25 | 2010-01-01  |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

schedule:

```
| day | month | name      | shifts |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
|   1 |     6 | Florin    |      0 |
|   1 |     6 | Andrei    |      1 |
|   1 |     6 | Alexandra |      2 |
|   1 |     6 | Emilia    |      3 |
|   1 |     6 | Nicoleta  |      4 |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to interrogate table "workers" to give me 2 random names, with minimum shifts number, and workers should not be in vacation period. Also work history must be greater than 18 MONTHS.
In this case, the query i need should return Florin and Andrei.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work as supposed:

```
SELECT name FROM workers WHERE (CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN vacationA AND vacationB) AND workhistory > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND name IN (SELECT name FROM schedule ORDER BY shifts LIMIT 2) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

This query returns 
`1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you have got `name` column in `schedule` table already (although it's not a good design), you don't need a `join`. You can just use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`,.e.g.

```
SELECT name
FROM schedule
WHERE day ? AND month = ? --Remove this if there is no crriteria
ORDER BY shifts
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question, if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is just to sort the table by the number of shifts and grab the first two entries:

```
SELECT name FROM schedule ORDER BY shifts ASC LIMIT 2
```

I notice, however, that you already have an `ORDER BY` clause, so it seems you want the results in random order.

If you need the random order as well, then wrap the whole thing in a subquery like this:

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT name FROM schedule ORDER BY shifts ASC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question, if you can help.